# Configure Maven installation in Jenkins per individual job

Tags: maven, jenkins

Is there a way to configure Jenkins to use specific Maven installation per job?
e.g.
Job A - Maven 3.3.3
Job B - Maven 3.3.9

Comment: If you configure that in jenkins itself having different configuration you can of course select the version for a particular job...but if you have really such jobs which need a particular Maven version i would assume that your build not configred very well...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jenkins allows you to select which Maven installation to use per job. You can setup multiple installations of Maven, multiple settings configurations of Maven to be exact, through *Manage Jenkins* → *Configure System*.

Then to configure per job, in Jenkins, select your specific build job and choose *Configure.* From there, assuming it is a Maven project build, you should have option(s) under the **Build** section (might have to hit the *Advanced* button) where you can select the Maven settings for your installation you want.

khmarbaise's comment is very valid, though. Unless you have a very specific reason to downgrade Maven for a given job, your build shouldn't be too reliant on what minor versions of the build tool to use.

Comment: I believe I have a valid reason for that. How to configure it then? I have added multiple installations but how to assign versions to jobs?

Comment: What if I execute mvn as "Execute shell" ?

Comment: That is slightly different, since that would likely be using whatever the default Maven installation is on the Jenkins server. In order to use a different one, you'd probably have to execute `mvn` from within the installation directory of the one you want.

Answer (score 1):

For newer Jenkins versions, management of Maven installations is placed here:

Manage Jenkins → Global Tool Configuration → section Maven.

Per job configuration: "Maven Version" dropdown placed in "Build" section.